# PHP - PDO Running multiple select queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to populate a google map with information from a few different tables.

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset={$charset}", $user, $pass);

$new_qry = "SELECT * FROM Contractors WHERE `Name` = 'John';";
$new_qry.= "SELECT * FROM Interns WHERE `Name` = 'Mike'";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $new_qry );
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
    $new_lat = $row['Latitude'];
    $new_long = $row['Longitude'];
    .
    .
    .etc
```

I save the desired info and make a map marker for each result. But I do not get results from the second query. Is there another way to run multiple queries? I eventually want to have a lot more than 2 run at once.

Configuration :

- PHP version: 5.6+
- PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = 1

Comment: By default this does not make sense. Do the two queries return the same columns ? Otherwise, what would the resultset look like ?

Comment: "Is there another way to run multiple queries" Yes but i advice you not to using those.. Most likely you are looking for a `JOIN` or a `UNION ALL` here.. I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results.

Comment: There are a few differeneces between the tables but the information i need have the same column names.

Comment: I never recommend `extract()`. There is almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I suspect that you could pick a list of columns common to both tables and get all information in a single query, using `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude, ...
FROM Contractors 
WHERE `Name` = 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT Latitude, Longitude, ...
FROM Interns 
WHERE `Name` = 'Mike'
```

Please keep in mind that both unioned queries must return the same list of columns, with the same datatypes (unless MySQL is lax about that). It is a general requirement in SQL that a query must return a fixed set of columns with a consistent datatype in each column.

Comment: " It is a general requirement in SQL that a query must return a fixed set of columns." Yes indeed also the SQL standard says it is  required that the column should have the same datatype in the column between the two selects. In MySQL this is not required or a better word not enforced.

Comment: @RaymondNijland : yes it is an important thing to mention, thanks ! I updated my answer.

Comment: "unless MySQL is lax about that" Not unless MySQL/MariaDB does it that way, why is it so easy to SQL injected MySQL/MariaDB with a `UNION ALL database(), database()[....] ORDER BY 1, 2[,...] DESC LIMIT 1, 1#` it does not matter if the two columns from the first select are ints or not...if MySQL/MariaDb would enforce datatype it would be more a challenge because when you would have to go blind boolean based SQL injections.

Comment: I dont think this will work due to the tables not matching %100

Comment: @tdlanghe : instead of use `SELECT *`, you have to explictly list the columns to select (as showned in my example). With this technique you can arrange both queries to return the same set of columns.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks for y'alls help. About to make some crazy stored procedures